# Android ListItem half slide with touch move

Tags: android, listview, layout, touch, slide

Thanks for your valuable time. 
My question is, I want to create a ListView with immediate action on ListItems by sliding left of 40%.
I had tried with ViewFlipper, ViewSwtcher, but these controls are providing fully view switch feature , where I want only 40% to show next layer view. Below 2 images of my requirement prototype for your clear understanding.

I am not a frequently developer of Android, so please any help me on this how to implement.

[image: Normal view of ListItems]
[image: after slide view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to android too, but i found some example that does similar things that you want:
https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview
Hope that helps.